# Java reading text file using two loops

Tags: java, loops, bufferedreader

I'm away from my computer right now but I had an idea and I really wanna know if it'll work.

Would this rough code work for getting groups of lines out of a text file (using `BufferedReader br`):

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = ....;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while(line = br.readline() != null){
    if(line.equals("Group1"){
        while(line = br.readline() != "}"){
            list.add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Here would be the text file:

```
Group1
one
two
three
}
Group2
....
}
```

Comment: @Curi0us7 Yeah, I added the text file just for kicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use single loop like this:

```
boolean isGroup=false;
while(line = br.readline() != null){
    if(line.equals("Group1"){
      isGroup=true;
    }
    if(line.equals("}") && isGroup)
      isGroup=false;
    if(isGroup){
      //read line and check whether it is null or not
      list.add(line);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah if the double loop didn't work I was going to do it with a boolean. Thanks for the conformation.